# How to update a table by using a join of two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table with these columns:

```
Id int, Reference varchar(50), FileId int
```

The 'Reference' column always ends with a "D" or a "C". The `FileId` needs to be updated. On update I have a table varilable:

```
DECLARE @fileIds TABLE (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  [Type] varchar(1) NOT NULL
);
```

This table variable always has a maximum of 2 records and at least 1 record. The `Type` column has a value of "D" or "C"

Now I need to update my table by setting the `FileId` to match the corresponding file id. Is this the correct way to do the update:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET 
    FileId = f.Id
FROM
    myTable
    INNER JOIN @fileIds f ON RIGHT(s.Reference, 1) = p.[Type]
```

Comment: Your method is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think missed alias but you have used two different alias. So, "Reference" and "Type" column is which tables to belongs because use others alias.

Update using join syntax.

```
UPDATE
    A
SET 
    A.FileId = B.Id
FROM 
    tableA AS A
INNER JOIN 
    tableb AS B ON A.Id = B.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed alias name of mytable

```
UPDATE s 
SET 
    FileId = f.Id
FROM
    myTable s
    INNER JOIN @fileIds f ON RIGHT(s.Reference, 1) = f.[Type]
```